# iPhone how hide volume overlay when press volume key

Tags: ios, iphone, volume, avcapturesession, mpvolumeview

I have do lots to solve it,like add MPVolumeView,someone says that system volume HUD
 will hide if you add a instance of MPVolumeView in current,but that not work

i add obsever to observe the volume's change，and take picture

but now i lost in how hide the volume HUD

I had tried the solution that add MPVolumeView instance 
but won't WORK
please give me another way to solve it

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code what you have tried.

Comment: @hinata then i capture still image in method :volumeDidChange,in addtion,i wanna hide volume HUD when press volume key,wish u can help me,

Answer (score 5):

You need to put volume overlay like this:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview: volumeView];
```

Now the custom overlay won't be visible. But keep in mind that you are not able to get action on pressing volume buttons you can only be notified about its effect - [changing a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868192/how-to-distinguish-on-ios-volume-button-clicked-from-setting-it-by-a-software)

Comment: you mean I add volumeView in viewDidLoad or my method "volumeDidChanged" when I observe volume key pressed?

Comment: it can be in viewDidLoad

Comment: actually,I had tried ur solution,but I'll tried that again,wish it'll work thank you for ur answer

Comment: You saved my day ! Thx

Comment: It's working for me but due to this Airplay icon is showing on the top left corner.