# Is it possible to disable volume buttons in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, volume

I am developing a Game and I would like to disable the volume buttons when I am playing (because the user has to use the accelerometer and could accidentally press it).
Is it possible at all?

Comment: Do not think so. This would affect the ringer control as well, which is probably not what Apple wants.

Comment: I think there are ways to hide the overlay volume popup, I've definitely seen apps that do this. Apparently involved MPVolumeView, but also looks like this might not work in iOS 8.

Comment: @shim I agree with you, I don't remember what apps but I've also seen some hiding the overlay. I will have a look if possible to do it.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I was able to hide the volume overlay:
[Hide Volume Overlay][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521090/iphone-how-hide-volume-overlay-when-press-volume-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

[This Q&A explains how to set up a volume listener.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28471481/335858)

[This Q&A explains how to hide volume overlays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521090/iphone-how-hide-volume-overlay-when-press-volume-key)

**Old answer:** This has not been possible in the past, because the practice has been explicitly disallowed by the [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) which no longer apply:

> Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected