# iOS Swift: How to hide the volume control overlay?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I would like to hide the volume control overlay in my iOS app. Even when the volume buttons are Pressed.

Does anyone know how this works?
Best regards

Comment: You might want to specify whether you're talking about iOS or macOS

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t see how my suggestion was aggressive.

Comment: I did not “dislike” your question. I was not the one that downvoted it. On SO, votes are anonymous — usually not good to assume that you know it was a specific person. In fact, I’ve upvoted now to balance out and will add iOS to the tags for you since I believe that the platform was the only relevant information you were missing. I was just trying to help clarify. No, I don’t know specifically how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25521910/5757843) is similar to what you are asking for. I have converted it to Swift:

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
self.view.addSubview(volumeView)
```